# Cracking Mysql 5 Hash using Hashcat

Tags: hash, password-cracking, hashcat

I am practicing cracking MYSQL5 hash using hash cat, however, for a reason or another, it finishes the cracking process too fast -within 30 seconds- without giving any results/errors back.

I doubted that I am using an incorrect hash type, however, I double checked using hash-identifier and other tools as well.

Here is the output:

```
root@k:~/Desktop# cat hash
63e5c2e178e611b692b526f8b6332317f2ff5513

root@k:~/Desktop# hashcat -m300 -a0 hash rockyou.txt 
Initializing hashcat v0.47 by atom with 8 threads and 32mb segment-size...

Added hashes from file hash: 1 (1 salts)
Activating quick-digest mode for single-hash

NOTE: press enter for status-screen


Input.Mode: Dict (rockyou.txt)
Index.....: 1/5 (segment), 3627099 (words), 33550343 (bytes)
Recovered.: 0/1 hashes, 0/1 salts
Speed/sec.: 796.54k plains, 796.54k words
Progress..: 3627099/3627099 (100.00%)
Running...: 00:00:00:04
Estimated.: --:--:--:--


Input.Mode: Dict (rockyou.txt)
Index.....: 2/5 (segment), 3351796 (words), 33550341 (bytes)
Recovered.: 0/1 hashes, 0/1 salts
Speed/sec.: 779.88k plains, 779.88k words
Progress..: 3351796/3351796 (100.00%)
Running...: 00:00:00:04
Estimated.: --:--:--:--


Input.Mode: Dict (rockyou.txt)
Index.....: 3/5 (segment), 3323233 (words), 33550343 (bytes)
Recovered.: 0/1 hashes, 0/1 salts
Speed/sec.: 724.21k plains, 724.21k words
Progress..: 3323233/3323233 (100.00%)
Running...: 00:00:00:05
Estimated.: --:--:--:--


Input.Mode: Dict (rockyou.txt)
Index.....: 4/5 (segment), 3488103 (words), 33550343 (bytes)
Recovered.: 0/1 hashes, 0/1 salts
Speed/sec.: 768.58k plains, 768.58k words
Progress..: 3488103/3488103 (100.00%)
Running...: 00:00:00:04
Estimated.: --:--:--:--


Input.Mode: Dict (rockyou.txt)
Index.....: 5/5 (segment), 553093 (words), 5720127 (bytes)
Recovered.: 0/1 hashes, 0/1 salts
Speed/sec.: 824.46k plains, 824.46k words
Progress..: 553093/553093 (100.00%)
Running...: --:--:--:--
Estimated.: --:--:--:--

Started: Mon May  5 04:43:41 2014
Stopped: Mon May  5 04:44:17 2014
root@k:~/Desktop#
```

I am really confused since I tried hashcat with other hashes and it works fine ! But why it did not work with this one ?

Aside from this, I have seen multiple sites the provide cloud cracking for money. Does anybody have any recommendations/experience with such service ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your hashcat appears to be working correctly.  30 seconds is about how long it takes mine to run through every password in rockyou.txt

It looks like the password is not in rockyou.txt which only contains a few hundred thousand passwords.

I suggest you use some rules to make it guess some variations on the passwords in rockyou and/or find a larger dictionary.

d3ad0ne.rule will take a nice long time...

a command might be

```
hashcat -m 300 -a 0 -r rules/d3ad0ne.rule hash rockyou.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will give it a try and let you know how it goes !